# On Network call response data stores successfully but not present while reading. Using SnappyDb for storing the data.

Tags: android, database, android-volley, snappydb

I am making a network call through volley. On Response success I am trying to store data through SnappyDb which shows that it has stored successfully. But while reading any data is not present. But if I have data outside of response than it saves and reads too. Below is my code. I am struggling in this from last 2 days. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
private void makeApiCall(String key) {
    if (Utility.isNetworkAvailable(AddCustomerActivity.this)) {
        final String finalKey = key;
        showProgressDailog("Adding...");
        NetworkEb.apiCallAddUser(customerEb, (key != null && !key.contains(":"))? true : false, new OnJsonResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    int serverId = response.getInt("id");
                    customerEb.setKey(serverId + "");
                    customerEb.setSync(true);
                    snappyDbUtil.saveObjectFromKey("customer", DbName.CUSTOMER.name(), customerEb);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String response) {
                Utility.showToast("Upload failed! Try Again");
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    } else {
        if (key == null) {
            key = snappyDbUtil.getNewKey(DbName.CUSTOMER.name());
            customerEb.setKey(key);
            customerEb.setSync(false);
            Utility.showToast("Saved locally");

        }
        snappyDbUtil.saveObjectFromKey(key, DbName.CUSTOMER.name(), customerEb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. You need to save the data in UI thread by calling this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            itemDataModel.setKey("ITEMS:" + key);
                            itemDataModel.setSync(true);
                            snappyDbUtil.saveObjectFromKey(itemDataModel.getKey(), DbName.ITEMS.name(), itemDataModel);
                        }
                    });
```

Here you have to also care for the keys to store with which only saves if we provide a db name as shown in the above code.